# screen tearing on intel integrated graphics in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: intel-graphics

I have a problem with screen tearing on a newly built pc.

what i've done so far is: sudo nano `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`

and I've added:

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "Intel Graphics"
Driver "intel"
Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"
Option "TearFree" "true"
Option  "TripleBuffer" "true"
EndSection
```

Any idea, how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Provide more specific detail on the Intel graphics card (lshw will contain a section). Can you confirm this is a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04, i.e., not an upgraded version?

Comment: Can you update your question with results from: `lshw | grep display -A12`